# Tkinter Import Error on Puppy Linux

Tags: linux, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm having a few problems running tkinter on my Puppy Linux laptop using Geany to write and execute the code. I've got Python 3.1 running ok, but whenever I try to

```
import tkinter
```

I get the following error message:

```
file "/usr/lib/python3.1/tkinter/__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
import _tkinter

UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1 codec can't encode characters in position 0-3: ordinal not in range(256)
```

I don't have the foggiest what's going on!

I changed the Geany filetypes.python document from:

```
compiler=python -m py_compile "%f"
run_cmd=python "5f"
```

which runs Python2 as the default (tkinter imports fine with this!), to:

```
compiler=python3.1 -c "import py_compile;py_compile.compile('%f')"
run_cmd=python3.1 "%f"
```

in order to allow me to use python 3.1 as the default. I did copy this code, rather than writing it as I'm not familiar with Linux.

I would like to know how I can successfully use tkinter with Python3 on PuppyLinux. I'm not tied in to using Geany, so any help is appreciated!

Rich